# Fetch Value from Json without DeserializeObject C#

Tags: c#

Following Json is return from API call.

```
{
    "version": "dddf2222",
    "data": {
        "account": {
            "username": "34343",
        },
    },
    "error": 0
}
```

I want to fetch value of username without DeserializeObject.

Comment: why not deserialize?

Answer (score 0):

```
dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myJson);

Console.WriteLine(stuff.data.account.username);
```

---

using `using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`

```
dynamic stuff = JObject.Parse(myJson);
Console.WriteLine(stuff.data.account.username);
```